# Norm of $ \zeta_n^a + \zeta_n^{-a} - \zeta_n^b - \zeta_n^{-b} $.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Set $ \zeta_n = e^{2\pi i/n} $ as the $ n $-th root of unity. Consider the expression
$$
z = \zeta_n^a + \zeta_n^{-a} - \zeta_n^b - \zeta_n^{-b}
$$
where $ 0 < b < a < n/2 $. I want to find the norm  (i.e. the constant of its minimal polynomial) of $ z $.

I have computed with Wolframalpha for few values of $ n $ and this is what I found:

- When $ n $ is prime, the norm is $ \pm n $, regardless of $ a, b $.
- When $ n = 2^k $, the norm is $ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 8 $.
- When $ n = p_1 ... p_m $, where $ p_i $ are prime, the norm is a multiple of some of the $ p_i $.

Is there a known formula for this value? And how does it depend on $ a, b $?

Answer (score 1):

As norm is multiplicative, it is a good idea to write the mentioned sum, say $z$ as a product. Notice that :
$$ \zeta^a + \zeta^{-a} = 2 \cos\left(2 \pi i \frac{a}{n}\right). $$
Therefore,
$$ z = 2 \cos\left(2 \pi i \frac{a}{n}\right) -2 \cos\left(2 \pi i \frac{b}{n}\right) = -4 \sin\left(2 \pi i \frac{a+b}{n}\right) \sin\left(2 \pi i \frac{a-b}{n}\right)    $$
The rest is now to determine minimal polynomials of $\sin\left(2\pi i \frac{a}{n}\right)$. Googling provides a lot of articles on the matter.